# flex videodisplay does not maintain aspect ratio

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, aspect-ratio, videodisplay

i have a videoDisplay component inside a group and the following code for it:

```
<mx:VideoDisplay id="videoDisplay" width="100%" height="100%"
                 maintainAspectRatio="true" 
                 creationComplete="videoDisplay_creationComplete();"
         addedToStage="videoDisplay_addedToStageHandler(event)"/>
```

but it does not maintain the aspect ratio when my app resizes, what can i do?? i show the video based on the input from my webcam..any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So the issue seems to be with the Web Cam giving improper width and height to the video display, could you also share the code where you input the web cam to video display

Thanks
Raj